# How to change format after convert column into DateTime in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following dataframe, see output attached:

```
Currency    Date    Closing Price (USD) 24h Open (USD)  24h High (USD)  24h Low 
0   BTC 01/10/2013        123.65          124.30          124.75        122.56
1   BTC 02/10/2013        125.46          123.65          125.76        123.63
2   BTC 03/10/2013        108.58          125.46          125.67         83.33
3   BTC 04/10/2013        118.67          108.58          118.68        107.06
4   BTC 05/10/2013        121.34          118.67          121.94        118.01
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
273 BTC 08/04/2021       56508.94       58030.62        58645.77        55541.91
273 BTC 09/04/2021       57880.91       55996.08        58179.66        55758.49
273 BTC 10/04/2021       58171.91       58094.74        58880.82        57717.86
273 BTC 11/04/2021       59295.95       58149.65        61065.22        57924.08
273 BTC 12/04/2021       59822.90       59765.10        60588.47        59229.86
```

As I need to extract month and make some groupby with the "Date" column data, I convert it into datetime, see code attached:

```
#datatime format
btc_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(btc_df['Date'])
```

After doing this, pandas is reading the date column as yyyy-dd-mm. This is a problem because as you can imagine data is not correctly treated. See output again:

```
Currency    Date    Closing Price (USD) 24h Open (USD)  24h High (USD)  24h Low 
0   BTC 2013/01/10        123.65          124.30          124.75        122.56
1   BTC 2013/02/10        125.46          123.65          125.76        123.63
2   BTC 2013/03/10        108.58          125.46          125.67         83.33
3   BTC 2013/04/10        118.67          108.58          118.68        107.06
4   BTC 2013/05/10        121.34          118.67          121.94        118.01
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
273 BTC 2021/08/04       56508.94       58030.62        58645.77        55541.91
273 BTC 2021/09/04       57880.91       55996.08        58179.66        55758.49
273 BTC 2021/10/04       58171.91       58094.74        58880.82        57717.86
273 BTC 2021/11/04       59295.95       58149.65        61065.22        57924.08
273 BTC 2021/12/04       59822.90       59765.10        60588.47        59229.86
```

I've tried the following code in order to change this issue:

```
btc_df['Date'] = btc_df['Date'].dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```

But when I run this code I get the following error:

> AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Can someone explain me why I'm getting this date format and how to fix it? I would like to have all my data correctly assigned to every day and month and not as it is now.

Thanks!

Comment: it seems your input dates are formatted day-month-year. however by default, pd.to_datetime will assume month-day-year. see Pedro's answer how to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Function `pd.to_datetime` can receive a parameter `format` in order to specify the desired date format:

```
btc_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(btc_df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

You can check all the parameters in https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: for the OP's input, it should not be necessary to set a specific format. Instead, setting keyword `dayfirst=True` should suffice.

Comment: Thanks @PedroGarcia and @MrFuppes! Seems it's working. My mistake was trying to get a yyyy-mm-dd format when it's not necessary to perform my operations!!